# Mapping between pandas MultiIndex and sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have pivoted a DataFrame with a MultiIndex on both rows and columns. I am going to transform the dataframe into a `scipy.sparse` matrix such that I can use it as a input to another library.

How can I preserve the mapping between the sparse matrix and the index of the pivoted DataFrame? E.g. row 1 of the sparse matrix corresponds to these two groups in the MultiIndex, and similarly, column 1 in the sparse matrix corresponds to these groups in the column MultiIndex

Edit: I guess the simplest way will be to convert the DataFrame to a sparse matrix, do the matrix factorization, convert the output of the matrix factorization back to a DataFrame and add the original MultiIndex

Edit2: Code sample by popular request

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: import scipy.sparse as sparse

In [4]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B', 'C'],
   ...:                                 ['D', 'E', 'F']],
   ...:                                 names=['Index1', 'Index2'])

In [5]: col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],
   ...:                                 ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']],
   ...:                                 names=['Col1', 'Col2'])

In [6]: data = np.ones((9,9))

In [7]: data.ravel()[np.random.choice(data.size, 70, replace=False)] = np.nan

In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, idx, col)

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
Col1             1              2             3
Col2             4    5    6    7    8   9   10   11   12
Index1 Index2
A      D       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
       E       1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
       F       NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
B      D       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
       E       NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
       F       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
C      D       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
       E       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
       F       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

In [10]: sparse.csr_matrix(df)
Out[10]:
<9x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 81 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

So, lets say I want to get the values in the sparse matrix corresponding to index 'A' and 'D' in column index 1. In pandas I can simply

`In [11]: df.loc[("A", "D"), "1"]
Out[11]:
Col2
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
Name: (A, D), dtype: float64`

But how to do this with the sparse matrix? Hence my question of the mapping between the sparse matrix and the pandas MultiIndex

Comment: It's difficult to grasp the problem without any data. I would provide input and expected output.

Comment: @kull1n, I have now put some example code in the original post. Please have a look if this made the problem clearer

Answer (score 0):

You could create your custom mapping functions `map_row` and `map_column` as dictionaries which will map from `MultiIndex` tuples to `Integer` index.

```
def map_row(r1, r2):
    mapping = dict(zip(df.index, range(len(df.index))))
    return mapping[(r1, r2)]

def map_column(c1, c2):
    mapping = dict(zip(df.columns, range(len(df.columns))))
    return mapping[(c1, c2)]
```

And then slice the sparse matrix like:

```
matrix[map_row("A", "E"), map_column("1","4")]

1.0
```